# Can i create users with passwords in openldap on non secure port 389

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

I am working on an application where we need to create user with passwords within Open LDAP. The problem is i don't have a relevant certificate which i can add to the truststore. I will get this certificate in some time but i can't wait for that.

I know that in Active Directory if i want to do such a thing i must have a 128 bit SSL connection between client and server and i have to use unicodePwd attribute but i am guessing that for open ldap i don't need any ssl connection and the password would be saved in the attribute userPassword so i can add the user with password over port 389. Are my assumptions correct?

Can anybody please point me to setup openldap on windows environment as well as this will just be used for my own tests. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am guessing that for open ldap i don't need any ssl connection and the password would be saved in the attribute userPassword so i can add the user with password over port 389. Are my assumptions correct?

Yes, you *can* do it, but it isn't advisable, as you will be transmitting passwords in plaintext. You should really go the extra yard and set it up for SSL as well, on port 636, or with the STARTTLS option on port 389 if port conservation is an issue.

> Can anybody please point me to setup openldap on windows environment as well as this will just be used for my own tests.

It's all documented at http://openldap.org. Windows-specific instructions will depend partly on which Windows port of OpenLDAP you're using. I'm aware of at least three.

Comment: I am not concerned about plain password because we will be switching to AD after some time and this is just for my dev tests but your answer was quite useful. I will be using 389 if that answers your second question.

Comment: Err, `389` is not OpenLDAP. So why did you tag your question `OpenLDAP`?